# Parenthesis matching code in python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have written following code and it was working fine.But One of the case it is failing.I tried but not able to fix this issue.

```
#!/usr/bin/env py
import itertools
import sys
import sympy
import re
import pprint
def extract_next_state(s):
    p = re.compile('(\()|(\))')
    depth = 0
    startindex = None
    start_point = False
    for m in p.finditer(s):
        if m.group(1):          # (
            depth += 1
            print "depth (", depth
            if not start_point:
                startindex = m.start()
                start_point = True
        elif m.group(2):          # )
            depth -= 1
            print "depth )", depth
            if depth == 0:
                return s[startindex:m.end()]
    return s[startindex:] + ')' * depth

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #data = ['next_state=(~SE&((~B2&D)|(B2&lq))|(SE&SI))']
    #data = ['next_state=((~SE&((A1&A2)|(B1&B2)))|(SE&SI)))']
    #data = ['next_state=((((~SE&((A1&A2)|(B1&B2)))|(SE&SI)))']
    data = ['next_state=(D1&S&!SE)|(!S&(!SE&D0))|(SE&SI))']
    data_1 = data[0].split(',')
    com = None
    for item in data_1:
        if item.find('next_state=')!= -1:
            item_list = item.split('=')
            item_op = extract_next_state(item_list[1])
            print item_op
```

output:

> (D1&S&!SE)

Expected :

> (D1&S&!SE)|(!S&(!SE&D0))|(SE&SI)

Comment: Regular expressions can't be used for nested constructs, like for example parentheses inside parentheses.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, that depends on the regex flavor. In PCRE it's as simple as: `(?:[^()]|\((?R)\))*`.

Comment: @Qtax I don't know if I would call that *simple* though. :)

Comment: Are you trying to make a logic parser? Why not use something like [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) and save yourself a load of hassle. I can post an answer with the code to do this if you want?

Comment: In very specific case, I need this. I am not trying to write any parser.

Comment: Regardless of best way to do it, why does that last example have an unbalanced `)` at the end? Surely to be parsed like the others, it requires another `(` at the start... otherwise the first bit in `(...)` is a perfectly reasonable answer as that's the first point it balances

Comment: But I need to traverse upto the last string

Comment: What I'm saying is: how do you expect it to work if your input is malformed?

Comment: hmm ok..I got the point. But may be one of exception. we can not change input as we reading from location. will it better I put the condition like string has not reached end.

Comment: @AbhishekGoswami just to complete my previous point before I run away, you may want to look at the [code I just pushed](https://github.com/hgomersall/python-boolean).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You checking for `depth == 0` as condition for returning from `extract_next_state()`. That is `extract_next_state()` returns once the matching closing parenthesis to the first opening parenthesis is found. The rest of the string is then not checked for any further parenthesis of course.

It's hard to recommend a solution without knowing what rules for "next_state" or the grammar for allowd expressions. But from the last line `extract_next_state` it seems you wish to close any open parenthesis. So a possible solution may be:

```
def extract_next_state(s):
    p = re.compile('(\()|(\))')
    depth = 0
    startindex = None
    endindex = None
    for m in p.finditer(s):
        if m.group(1):          # (
            depth += 1
            print "depth (", depth
            if not startindex:
                startindex = m.start()
        elif m.group(2):          # )
            depth -= 1
            print "depth )", depth
            if depth == 0:
                endindex = m.end()
    return s[startindex:(endindex if depth == 0 else None)] + ')' * depth
```

If with the last closing parenthesis all pairs are matched, the rest of the string is discarded, else a matching number of closing parentheses will be added.

Comment: sometime simple thing people make complicated like I did. accept your answer